My Laptop have bios issue and wont boot from anything
I have a hp pavillion gaming laptop i5-10300h with insyde bios and Intel optane memory.  My laptop wont boot anything like from pendrive or hdd nothing. I had BSOD issue. 3.3v power supply was bad. I took it to Hp they said no fix, then took it to local shop, he fixed it but he changed my Laptop serial number. Now my laptop runs for one day and next morning it wont boot from anything. Everytime he does the same thing and next morning my laptop stop working.
I can go into bios and run hardware checks everything is working fine. just it wont boot anything and HP service center cant fix it.
So now i am thinking to reprogram bios chip. Like erase it then reprogram. Can you please guide me through it.

So you replaced the motherboard. It’s entirely possible the new motherboard has its own problems since it no doubt was from a donor device. Do you have the skills to remove the chip, program the chip, and install the chip? What program would install to the chip, trying to understand, the reason you suspect the bios chip.

No, local guy replaced 3.3 v power supply on the motherboard. I earlier had this issue, that time 5v power supply gone bad. But back then HP bios had ctrl + A or N option to change serial number and add your laptop details. I cant remember clearly but I google and follow steps it was fixed. another time I reinstalled windows then it gave me option, a pop up came did you changed motherboard and i followed details and it was fixed. This time it is stuck. and noting is working. Earlier I installed windows 10 by connecting ssd to usb.  now you cant do that with windows 11. and I am stuck here.

No I donot have tools to remove chip. I was thinking if there is a way to short pins to reset chip then run a bios update from usb.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the serial number of the laptop changed, the technician replaced the motherboard, I can almost guarantee you that they didn’t diagnose the 3.3v circuit especially since the serial number changed

He told me he changed bios chip on motherboard. and everytime he does that, I dont know why. I dont think he changed the board. He charged me around 70$ for fix. I dont think he will change motherboard. and it is not a common laptop to find spare easily. Plus he made me sign all components when he take in laptop..

I know it had to do with bios or serial number or windows something, it is not a hardware issue. So I am trying to find a solution. My laptop has gone a junk box.

This seems a hardware issue, beyond the scope of SuperUser.

I am certain this is not hardware because i have faced this issue earlier. Just earlier methods i used are not working now. I am posting my issue on different forums. If someone has faced a similar issue can help me.

interestingly that local guy always change serial number to a same serial number. He has saved a copy of working bios for each type board, he put that copy on the board after hardware fix. If he again copy same bios on laptop, my laptop will work for one day then it wont work.(i am assuming this). because he also donot know what is the problem. After 2-3 times he gave up, said he cant fix this issue.  Hp should be able to fix this, but they always say buy new laptop. This cant be fix.. I am no technician, just have head banged so much on this laptop, now know entire power on sequence of laptop
